# How to turn summarized product into chart

Tags: r

I am very new to R and have learned only the basics.  I have created this code, which works fine, but I'd like to turn this into a chart:

```
all_data_clean %>% 
  group_by(month,member_casual) %>% 
  summarize(ave_trip=mean(trip_time))
```

Is there a way to add this summarization to a ggplot code?  I keep getting errors when I try to add it.  If not, what would my other options be for getting this data into a chart?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
all_data_clean %>% 
  group_by(month = factor(month, levels = month.name),member_casual) %>% 
  summarize(ave_trip=mean(trip_time), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = ave_trip, fill = member_casual)) %>%
     geom_col()
```

Comment: Thanks!  How can I get the months to show up in chronological order rather than alphabetically?

Comment: @TriciaTavis can you show the values in 'month' column

Comment: They are formatted as Character and are listed as October, November, December, etc.  I created a "month" column by extracting just the month from a column that had date data like this:  2020-10-08 16:50:57 because I was trying to group it just by month.  The data is from October 2020-September 2021 though, so now sure how I could go from October....September with my new column of just months.  It put it on the chart from left to right in alphabetically order.  I wasn't sure how to extract just the month from the full date column, but have it on the chart from Oct 2020 thru Sept 2021.  THANKS!

Comment: @TriciaTavis try the update

Comment: OK, that worked for starting Jan chronologically to Dec.  I think I can tinker with the month column to add the year and then when I do the add you suggested it'll start with Oct 2020.  THANK YOU!  Do you have any suggestions for classes, books, etc for me to move up from my very beginner level?

Comment: @TriciaTavis you can go through any docs in the web for learning.  More important is to practice i.e. spend some time daily in programming